# HTML5 svg tag and alt attribute

Tags: html, svg

Not an expert in HTML and checking the correct behavior of an HTML parser (looking for correct behavior according to html5 not good or expect (we can handle that later)).

In the new HTML5 <svg> tag is it valid to place the "alt" attribute?

```
<svg width="120" height="35" alt="Stuff">
  {{ STUFF }}
</svg>
```

Or should the <svg> be imbedded inside an <img> to achieve this?

```
<img alt="Stuff">
   <svg width="120" height="35">
      {{ STUFF }}
   </svg>
</img>
```

Comment: `alt` attribute is not valid on the `svg` element, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg#Specific_attributes) for available attributes. `<img>` tags must also have a `src` attribute.

Comment: @KyleNeedham: So what is the conical way to put alternative text on a page for an imbedded svg image (ie for not visual browsers).

Comment: You could do `<img src="image.svg" alt="alt text here" onerror="this.src=image.png;this.onerror=null;">` that way you can get support for most browsers (even IE6).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697100/accessibility-recommended-alt-text-convention-for-svg-and-mathml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SVG doesn't have an alt attribute, it uses a `<desc>` child tag instead.

```
<svg width="120" height="35">
  <desc>Stuff</desc>
  {{ STUFF }}
</svg>
```