# Can I use alt and title properties within SVG elements?

Tags: html, svg, tags, title, alt

To make my inline SVG image more searchable by google, can you add alt/title properties/attributes within svg elements such as "path" "circle" "line" etc?

I already know that you can use a title tag within the "svg" tag, like this..

```
<svg>
<title>this is a title tag.</title>
</svg>
```

Below is an example of what I am talking about.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1">
    <style type="text/css">

    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    </style>
    
    <path class="st0" title=“this is what I am talking about” d="M567,1136.2l37,10.9c13.3,3.9,27.2,3.1,39.9-2.4l0.6-0.3"/>
    
    <line id="hi2" class="st5" alt=“This is what I am Talking About” x1="72" y1="-169.7" x2="108" y2="-169.7"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I am aware, alt text cannot be used on SVGs. You are right in using `<title>` tags, but you can also add in `<desc>` to add more information.

Take a look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4756461/3909886 for a more detailed look into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

title as an attribute has no meaning in SVG, its equivalent as you point out in the question is the `<title>` element.

alt as an attribute also has no meaning, the SVG equivalent is the [`<desc>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#DescriptionAndTitleElements).

Comment: How about the meaning of when you hover it, show the title as a tooltip to the user, like every other element does.

Comment: @run_the_race the question already states that and I say it does in the answer.