# How to add images in HTML while satisfying web accessibility guidelines

Tags: html, image, accessibility, wai-aria

I am currently studying the web accessibility guidelines that concern HTML5.

Concerning **images**, I am currently adding images in HTML as follows:

```
<!-- Normal Images -->
<img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300x300" title="Image Placeholder" alt="Image Placeholder" aria-labelledby="Image Placeholder" width="300" height="300">

<!-- Decorative images -->
<img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/100x100" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" alt="" width="100" height="100">
```

1. Is it recommended by WAI-ARIA to add both `aria-labelledby` and `alt` tags **together** for normal images? or is there something else that I should adopt?
2. Do I need to add `role="presentation"`, `aria-hidden="true"`, and `alt=""` to every decorative image? All three of them should go together? or only one of them? (if only one or two of them then which ones?)

Comment: You should've tried and validated yourself!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Validation works in many cases. I am asking to understand the best practices. Validation tools are not perfect as well compared to how web accessibility experts see things.

Comment: Guidelines are guidelines, it's important that the screenreader doesn't read the image or that the image isn't getting in the way of the content. Test it yourself to be sure that your content can be reached and read without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Is it a good practice to add both `aria-labelledby` and `alt` tags together for normal images? or is there a better practice that I should adopt.

#### aria-labelledby

No, in fact adding `aria-labelledby` and `alt` together will result in some screen readers reading the name twice. Just use an `alt` attribute, that is what it is there for, it has the widest support (100%) and will do the job just fine.

Also `aria-labelledby` requires at least one element in the DOM that contains text, you reference it by ID. You can have more than one label too just for reference. It is designed to be used on other elements that can't be labelled using semantic HTML, not really for images (there are always exceptions but they are rare and this is general guidance).

e.g.

```
<span id="ID1">Read First</span>
<span id="ID2">You can add a second label that will be read second</span>
<div aria-labelledby="ID1 ID2"></div>
```

#### title attribute

Also don't use a `title` attribute unless you are planning on making it the same as the `alt` attribute. Otherwise mouse users get a different experience to screen reader users as the `title` attribute is not accessible to most screen readers. See this [in-depth answer I gave about the `title` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559067/tool-tip-content-is-not-accessible-using-keyboard/60581000#60581000) and how to roll an accessible version if you want to use it.

### accessible image example

So your final, accessible image would look like this:-

```
<img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300x300" alt="Image Placeholder" width="300" height="300">
```

Perfectly accessible and easy to maintain.

---

### Do I need to add role="presentation", aria-hidden="true", and alt="" to every decorative image? All three of them should go together? or only one of them? (if only one or two of them then which ones?)

#### alt attribute

All you need to do is add an empty `alt` attribute. Notice how I said empty and not null.
e.g. `alt=""` NOT just `alt`. Using `alt` as a null attribute will result in it being ignored by some screen readers so the file name will get read out.

#### role="presentation"

For completeness you can add `role="presentation"` but it will not add any extra support as far as I am aware.

With that being said I personally add `role="presentation"` to decorative images as our unit testing will flag any empty `alt` attributes unless this is added. This was a deliberate decision so when we run tests we don't keep checking the same empty `alt` attributes are correct.

As support for empty `alt` attributes is also at 99/100% it is also perfectly valid and accessible to just use `alt=""`.

#### aria-hidden

The only place (well the main time, there are always exceptions) where you would want to use `aria-hidden` on an external image is if you are going to dynamically hide and show it. Some screen readers monitor WAI-ARIA changes better than DOM changes.

#### aria-hidden and inline SVGs

I would recommend adding  `aria-hidden="true"`, `role="presentation"` and `focusable="false"` on inline SVGs that are purely decorative though as Internet Explorer can sometimes allow them to be focused.

Note that you don't use `alt` attributes on inline SVGs anyway.

#### decorative images examples

So your final decorative image would be:-

```
<!--all image types loaded externally using `img` including SVGs-->
<img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/100x100" alt="" width="100" height="100">
<!--exception for inline SVGs due to focus bug in IE-->
<svg aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" focusable="false">...</svg>
```

### final note on WAI-ARIA

WAI-ARIA is there to provide information when there is no semantic way to do so.

Adding extra WAI-ARIA all over actually makes accessibility worse. You should always start with 'is there a native way to give the information to a screen reader', if there is, WAI-ARIA is not needed or in fact recommended.

### After Thought

I mentioned [inline SVGs not using the `alt` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33317583/2702894), instead you want to use `<title>` as part of the SVG.  Read this [quick article on accessible SVGs](https://www.sitepoint.com/tips-accessible-svg/) for a quick overview.